# Create a column includes all confidence intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, survival-analysis, confidence-interval, cox

I have a code like that :

```
library("survival")
library("survminer")

data("lung")

res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

x<-confint(res.cox)
```

I am looking to get all the confidence intervals, not only the upper and lower bands. So I will have a confidence interval for each participant (N=228). Actually, I need to plot the confidence intervals with their distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to assign it to the data is :

```
lung$CI<- predict(res.cox)
```